# SMTP server to be used for Email Marketing Service

Tags: smtp

I am trying to build a email marketing service company. I am a .net programmer and I have played around trying to build a custom SMTP server but a lot of problems came up when domain keys into play. 
I am on the next step where I am looking for a professional that I could implement with .Net to send emails. It should provide full reporting. So I would be able to tell customers why their emails are bouncing and other other report such as other companies out there.

Just keep in mind I am not looking for check SMTP server used by spammers or any way like that. I am looking a way to implement a service like streamsend, mailchimp or constant contact and other well-known companies out there.

Please any reference or pointing me on the right way would be appreciated. Looking also for people that have experience on his field to collaborate or mentor me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you want to write your own SMTP service? Sounds like torture to me when there are plenty of perfectly good options out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Dont do email marketing. Don't. Streamsend, Mailchimp or Constant Contact are spammers by any other name. A pig with lipstick is still a pig.
2. If you must, just customize an existing solution. Very customizable: [sendmail](http://www.sendmail.org)

Answer (score 0):

Lyris, LSoft, Constant Contact and if you like programmable interfaces Mailgun